# How would a company write a magically binding NDA?

Tags: magic

In my setting an artificer company is being created which specializes in making advanced technology and is essentially bringing about an industrial revolution. They need to hire workers, and so have decided to have all the workers they bring on sign a magically binding NDA which will keep them from giving away company secrets. I want to have a version of the NDA written out but I have no clue how to go about writing one that would prevent people from sharing information by both physical (voice, writing, drawing, giving away prototypes or finished products/parts) and magical (mind reading, telepathy, etc).

The NDA would need to prevent the sharing of any kind of information, including both technical details, rumors, knowledge that the company has built up (such as how things like electricity as a concept works) and basically anything that the company would want to keep hidden from rival companies.

For the average worker the punishment for breaking the contract would be that the person breaking the contract would be unable to communicate anything regarding the company and would be compelled to make their way to the nearest company official to confess that they were divulging secrets and who they were divulging them to, and the effect would remain until the company official waived the effects.

The effects for a company official would be the same, but instead they would be compelled to go straight to the head of the company and only the head of the company could waive the effects.

The NDA would have a set end date but could have the condition that the person would no longer be bound by the NDA when the projects they were a part of are officially declassified. After a project is declassified they can talk about it, but the NDA would still apply to still classified projects.

How would I go about writing this so that it has no/as few loopholes as possible?

Comment: I Am Not A Lawyer. IANAL is commonly seen on Internet posts. You need to consult with a lawyer that handles magical contract law. Seeking legal consul from non-attorney, or even an attorney outside of their area of expertise is ill advised. Many communities have a referral service to help you find a lawyer, sometimes the local bar association is your best help in finding suitable counsel. Its also possible the local guild of mages could assist your search.

Comment: @GaryWalker Do you have the number for the local guild of mages? Been searching online, but every time I think I find something, I forget what I was looking for. Quite frustrating, really.

Comment: (1) To bring an industrial revolution you *want to* make all your inventions and processes public. That is why we use *patents*. A patent is basically the opposite of a trade secret: the inventor makes their invention public (thus, "patent", meaning wide open), and in exchange the state awards them a legal monopoly for a limited term. Trade secrets are exactly what you *do not want* when the goal is to kick-start an industrial revolution. (2) The means by which the NDA is enforced are irrelevant. They are rarely spelled out. There are many examples of NDAs on the net.

Comment: This seems more like a question about writing "how do I create a contract without obvious exploitable loopholes?" than it is about building a fictional world. For instance if your magic allows it you cast remove loopholes on the contract before it's presented for review.

Comment: @AlexP The patent idea could be a "frame challenge" answer

Comment: If this is for an RPG where the players might reasonably be expected to take the NDA as a puzzle to be cracked, I suggest you find some advice about real world contract law. If this is for a fictional setting where the content of the NDA doesn't need to be spelled out then I strongly suggest you don't... conserve details, that way there's no possibility of you being wrong or self-contradictory.

Comment: @sphennings **The OP is looking for the final product (contract), not the process of getting the final product.** Even if magic is used to remove loopholes, the OP still needs the final text of this NDA. Please note that contracts are essentially sets of rules, so they do fit even the current popular interpretation of worldbuilding as 'building rules and systems of fictional worlds'. This question is also not opinion-based and has one objectively best answer -- a set of rules that has 0 loopholes and fully prevents from sharing specified information with 3d parties.

Comment: @Otkin If they're asking about how to write a thing then they're not building a fictional world they're writing. I can say "in my world this contract has no loopholes" without writing the contract. If there was one objectively best answer why are there already 3 very different treatments of the problem?

Comment: @sphennings The absolute majority of 'how to write X?' questions are questions about *the content* of the desired text, not the process of writing. And yes, you can say that your contract has no loopholes. However, it is not the answer to this question, it is just handwaving. Please note that **the OP states that they want the text of their NDA** and not merely a description of it (see their comment to Willk's answer). The 3 provided answers do not attempt to answer the question since none of them talks about specific clauses that should be included in the desired document.

Comment: Willk and JamesFaix'a answers focus on the magic that can be used to prevent the spread of the information. flox talks about the general approach to writing legal documents. None of these answers suggests even one clause that could be included in the NDA and, therefore, fails to address the problem stated in the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Geas.**

> Also spelled alternately as geis,note  a geas (literally "taboo") is a
> form of magical compulsion or curse that originates in Celtic
> Mythology. Those under a geas are required to follow certain
> conditions or risk suffering a penalty bestowed by fate. If you have
> more than one such geas placed upon you, and they come into conflict,
> you're screwed. One of the most famous cases is that of Cú Chulainn,
> who was under numerous geasa, including that he must never eat the
> meat of a dog, nor refuse food offered by a woman. When an old hag
> offered him dog meat, he was forced to break one geas or the other,
> which led to his death the next day.
>
> A geas usually takes the form of either a command or a prohibition:
> "You shall do this," or "You shall not do this," occasionally followed
> with a "Or this will happen"

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Geas

I am thinking of Howls Moving Castle, where Sophie was magically prohibited from talking about her curse.  She figures out that is the case by trying.

I am struggling to think of the reader of a fantasy fiction who would be enthralled by the careful legalese of the NDA.  I think you would be better thinking of what happens when it is triggered and how the cunning spy figures out how to get around it.  Rather than show how it is written, the spy and confidante figure it out empirically with the spy trying various things and invoking various consequences.  Maybe the spy reveals his own secrets instead of the company secrets.  Maybe he can reveal half a secret one way and half a different way.  Maybe he can write a poem that alludes to the secret.  Fun!

Comment: I think it would be interesting to have the contract written out, at least a short one. It might encourage the reader to try and come up with possible ways around the contract themselves, and it would also reinforce that someone who manages to find a loophole is intelligent or thinks out side of the box because the reader themselves knows what the contract actually says. If (instead or writing it out) it is left vague then finding a loophole would be much easier, and someone doing so would be much less impressive.

Comment: @TheEmperorProtects - Charles Stross' Laundry files has this built into the Official Secrets Act.  There are no loopholes, because the adjudicator of whether a violation of the Act would be a violation of the Act is the brain of the person under the geas.  So if you try to think of a loophole, the geas still triggers because it's running inside your brain.

Answer (score 2):

**Ideosphere**

The laboratory is bound with an ideosphere enchantment which prevents certain ideas or the physical manifestations of those ideas from leaving.

If a mage attempts to physically remove an invention, it is met with the resistance of a forcefield. Even a well-intending janitor who doesn't know what it is cannot throw it out.

When mages go home for the day, they must extract any memories of the technology and leave it in a memory jar, or they too will not be able to leave. The next day they can restore the memories, or even share them with other mages for collaboration.

There is some rather subtle training that must take place to successfully follow the memory jar process without accidentally storing the memories about how the memory jar process works and getting confused.

The NDA is required by the Fairness in Mnemonomancy Act, passed by the Mages' Guild in 4E3529.

Answer (score 1):

### Wording depends on the entire legal framework, right down to your constitution.

Every agreement or contract requires a framework of law it resides in. This is more than just for reference: the wider framework of law outlines the rights, privileges, penalties or consequences that all citizens are entitled to, and so are the basis of all agreements.

So your NDA is only 'the surface'. Underneath these are layers of law that go right down to the basic structure of your system of governance. So:

1. Your NDA outlines the exchange/agreement, terms and **legal basis**
2. Your legal basis is the law, which is created by your '**government**', enforced by your 'police', and administered by your courts
3. Your 'government' creates the law, under the auspices and requirements of your **constitution**
4. Your constitution is the basis of all procedures and constraints, including perhaps even a basic clause of Human Rights, made right at the start by the 'founders', or a **foundation**.

So your NDA 'wording' really depends on the foundations it rests on, going right down all the way to the foundational constitution.

This, however, is a marvellous opportunity to do world-building, imagine if all these layers are constructed over history in your world, accumulating and creating the top-level agreements (in this case your NDA) that all agreements are made from.

For example:

1. Constitution: "All citizens must obey magic users" and "All citizens have a right to life."
2. Government: "Based on the constitution, we will create a Magic law that says everyone must do what a magic user says ('obey'), but without costing anyone their lives"
3. Law: "Magic Law: If you are given an instruction by a magic user, you must comply, unless the instruction results in a loss of your life. Penalty is 10 days in the castle basement."
4. NDA: "As within the Magic Law, You (the contractor) must not divulge, transmit, disseminate or cause to be divulged, transmitted or disseminated any magical secrets made by us (the principal). Penalty is as per the Magic Law." and so on (have a look at a publicly available NDA - these can go on for pages and pages).

The above is an extraordinarily simplistic example, but you can easily imagine the quick complexity and layering of legal language and agreements that make law one of the most largest professions, no matter what world you are in.